# Amazon FPS how do I make items appear in the checkout?

Tags: php, checkout, amazon-fps

How can I list the items the user has purchased on the amazon checkout screen? I'm checking items out from my store and using amazon just for payments, I do not checkout any amazon products.

The checkout screen just shows this and the name of the buyer:

```
Details: Cart
Total Amount: $3.19
```

Is there any way to list the items he has purchased there? I'm using the AmazonFPS php SDK.

Comment: Worked this way in my case:
  $items = implode("<br />", Set::extract($cart, 'Cart/CartItem/name'));

  $pipeline->addParameter("paymentReason", $items);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it:

```
$pipeline = new Amazon_FPS_CBUISingleUsePipeline(/*...*/)
//...
$items = implode("<br />", Set::extract($cart, 'Cart/CartItem/name'));
$pipeline->addParameter("paymentReason", $items);
```